# Matlabs "splitapply" used on functions with multiple parameters

Tags: matlab, apply

I don't understand matlabs `splitapply` function:

```
>> f=@(t,x) sum(sum(t),sum(x))

f =

  function_handle with value:

    @(t,x)sum(sum(t),sum(x))

>> splitapply(f,[1,0;0,0],[1,1;2,2],1:2)

ans =

     1     0
```

I expected the two matrices to be split into columns and the two first columns fed to f, resulting in a total sum of 4=(1+0)+(1+2). Then both the second columns should be fed to f, resulting in the number 3=(0+0)+(1+2).

So I expected

```
ans =

     4     3
```

But quite obviously that is not what happend. And I am not sure why. If I use `splitapply` on functions with only one argument, it seems to do what I expect:

```
>> splitapply(@sum,[1,1;2,3],1:2)

ans =

     3     4
```

I would be glad if someone could point out what is happening. This is the documentation if someone else can understand it better than me: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html

Comment: What it does: [1+0, 0+0]. So doesn't matter what your third argument here for splitapply is, you'll get the same result

Comment: @SardarUsama could you explain that in more detail? Why is it doing that? And how can I get it to actually split the matrices into columns and feed them one after the other to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want

```
f = @(t,x) sum([sum(t) sum(x)])
```

or

```
f = @(t,x) sum(t)+sum(x)
```

rather than

> `f = @(t,x) sum(sum(t), sum(x))`

The latter is interpreted as compute the sum of `sum(t)` *along the dimension given by `sum(x)`*.

With this correction,

```
>> f = @(t,x) sum([sum(t) sum(x)]);
>> splitapply(f,[1,0;0,0],[1,1;2,2],1:2)
ans =
     4     3
```

Comment: actually that was just a toy example for my other problem, if I didn't use the sums correctly then I'll come back with another example which hopefully represents my problem in my actual code better. Let me check. Yeah apparently that was also a problem. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I think it works as I expected and the code is broken due to something else. I'll just accept your answer.